# How does Windows 10 guess physical dimensions of a 1080p display?

Tags: windows, registry

I'm running Windows 10 1803 on a laptop, attached to a desktop display. Laptop's display resolution is same as the attached display, 1920x1080 pixel (namely "Full HD").  
However the screen sizes differ, the laptop has a 13" display and the desktop display is 27"...

By the settings option: `start->system->display` I can adjust scaling for each (!) display to the *lowest* scaling factor "100%" and a *highest* resolution of FullHD (1080p).  
This setting is fine for the laptop display. 
However, with the same setting for the 27" everything appears double sized ...

**Q1**: How does Windows 10 guess the (physical) dimensions of a screen display to get dpi be calculated "*per inch*"?

**Q2**: Is there any option to let Windows 10 to render a "virtual" screen resolution higher than the physical maximum on the 27" display?

**Q3**: Why does Windows 10 ignore the registry `dword` `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\LogPixels`, when I set the value from initial 96ppi to a higher resolution?

*Remark*: Since I do not work on a stationary desktop, buying a 4k display is definitely no option and no answer to this topic. 
 
However, using 2k+ displays would solve the problem since Windows will then calculate a reasonable dpi resolution for the attached displays.

Comment: It does not guess. It asks monitor about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data
BTW you're on a wrong site with your question. StackOverflow is about programming.

Comment: sorry, moved the question to superuser...